# angularjs return array from factory

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, factory

I'm trying to refactor my angular app. Therefore i have introduced a service.js file which includes a factory service. The code is like this :

```
app.factory('Categorien', function() {
var Categorien = {
    populate: function () {
        var _categorien = [];
        var bedragok = (function bedragOk(categorie) {
            return categorie.bedragAf > 0;
        });

        var categorienFilter = $scope.categorien.filter(bedragok);
        categorienFilter.forEach(function(item) {
            var dataArray = [];
            dataArray.push(item.omschrijving);
            dataArray.push(item.bedragAf);
            _categorien.push(dataArray);
        });
        return _categorien;
    }
};
return Categorien;
});
```

And in the controller I call this by :

```
        $scope.dataTable = Categorien.populate();
```

So the dataTable expects an array which function populate should return.

I'm doing something wrong so i hope you can help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: you function `bedragok` fn should be `var bedragok = function bedragOk(categorie) {
            return categorie.bedragAf > 0;
        };`

Comment: Factories/services in Angular are not associated with a `$scope` like a controller is. You should be getting an error when you do this: `var categorienFilter = $scope.categorien.filter(bedragok);` b/c the $scope is undefined. You are not really describing what is not working in your question.

Comment: In angularjs factories and services are singleton services. However, `$scope` - scopes can have multiple instances. Hence, you should not include `$scope` inside any of services / factories. Refer "https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services" - AngularJS docs for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use a custom filter if you only want to do the filtering. Then your code could look like in the demo below.

If you'd like to use a factory you can pass the array to your populate function like `$scope.dataTable = Categorien.populate(['your', 'array', 'here']);` or you could add your data to your factory with another method. As mentioned in the comments `$scope` should not be passed to a factory.

The following demo (or in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/e877tnxo/)) shows how it would work with a custom filter:

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .controller('MainController', MainController)
    .filter('categoryFilter', function() {
        return function(input) {
            var _categorien = [];
            var bedragok = (function bedragOk(categorie) {
                return categorie.bedragAf > 0;
            });

            var categorienFilter = input.filter(bedragok);
            categorienFilter.forEach(function(item) {
                var dataArray = [];
                dataArray.push(item.omschrijving);
                dataArray.push(item.bedragAf);
                _categorien.push(dataArray);
            });
            return _categorien;
        }
 });

function MainController() {
 this.data = [
        {
             bedragAf: 100,
             omschrijving: 'test'
        },
        {
             bedragAf: -100,
             omschrijving: 'test neg. value'
        },
        {
             bedragAf: 100,
             omschrijving: 'test2'
        }
    ];        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
    <pre>
raw: 
{{ctrl.data | json : 2}}
        
filtered:
{{ctrl.data | categoryFilter | json : 2}}
    </pre>
</div>
```